# Как динамически менять дополнительное полу в modx?

Tags: modx

Есть дополнительное поле с местами в автобусе, выполнено в виде галочки у каждого места. Автобусы есть с разным количеством мест. Как можно реализовать возможность выбора автобуса и вывод того количества мест, сколько именно в этом автобусе.

Answer (score 0):

Вложенная таблица в качестве TV вам подойдет, MIGX например так умеет.
Более подробно по ссылкам ниже:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45251908/modx-how-to-create-migx-inside-another-migx
2. https://forums.modx.com/thread/79637/migx-within-another-migx?page=2
3. https://web-revenue.ru/modx-revo/migx-v-migx